# The correct use of "sundering"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, gerunds

I'm writing a book in which one of the major events is a day that separates two major forces in the world.

It's meant to be a punishment from a high power, so at first I wanted to call it *The Day of Punishment*, but honestly that sounds like I put a minimum of effort into it and it just doesn't sound good.

I looked up a few words in a thesaurus and found *sunder*. So I thought of using *The Day of Sundering*, but I'm not quite sure if it makes grammatical sense, and whether it's the best choice available.

So in short, did I use the word *sundering* correctly? Or is there a better choice out there that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: [Rend](http://thesaurus.com/browse/rend) and its synonyms may be interesting

Comment: Why not just *The Day of Sunder*? Nicely reminiscent of thunder in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

*The Day of Sundering* is grammatically sound; *sundering* is the present participle of *[sunder](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sunder#Verb)*, a verb that means “To break or separate or to break apart, especially with force”, ie, to split something apart.

Regarding if “it would be the best choice available” and “is there a better choice out there that I'm not thinking of”, I think the answers are no, it's not the best; and yes, better choices exist.  Unfortunately I don't know what they are.  *The World Asunder* is perhaps more dramatic, but its meaning differs from *The Day of Sundering*.  While *The Day of Cleavage* is slightly dramatic and has the right meaning, it has another meaning as well that may mislead some readers.

Comment: The day of Cleavage is my kind of day. We need more cleavage out there ;)))